# Speeding up Scipy's RectBivariateSpline evaluation function

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, scipy, interpolation

My question regards using the `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline` function to interpolate a 2D mesh. I am essentially trying to emulate functionality of Matlab's interp2 function.

For a particular (light) use case, I call RectBivariateSpline on x and y vectors, which are regularly spaced, monotonically increasing vectors, e.g.:

```
x = np.arange(0., 20., 1.)  # shape (20,)
y = np.arange(0., 20., 1.)  # shape (20,)
```

and some 2D field, e.g.:

```
fld = np.reshape(np.arange(0., 400., 1.), (20, 20))  # shape (20, 20)
```

i.e.:

```
fn = sp.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x, y, fld)
```

To evaluate the interpolation, then, at particular xi, yi coordinates (or arrays, obeying numpy broadcasting), the docs advise to call the `RectBivariateSpline.ev` function, i.e.:

```
val1 = fn.ev(1, 1)  # Ans: 21
val2 = fn.ev([1, 2], [1, 2])  # Ans: [21, 22]
```

This allows the user to find one interpolated value, for say (xi, yi) = (1.5, 1.5), or many interpolated values, say on a particular domain (regular or irregular grid).

My question is this: for large xi, yi arrays, how can I make the fn.ev call faster?  Compared to the Matlab `interp2` call, it is pretty slow (by an order of magnitude or worse).

Following the function call in the debugger, I have found that `ev` is actually a wrapper for `RectBivariateSpline.__call__`. This again is a wrapper for a call to the fitpack functions (in C / Fortran) on which Scipy's interpolation functionality is based. The `__call__` function has an optional keyword `grid`, defaulted to `False` and absent from `ev`, which allows you to pass two vectors defining an orthogonal grid. Calling with `grid` set to `True` leads to the call of the fitpack routine `bispev` which is MUCH faster than the documented `ev` function which calls fitpack `bispeu`. (I assume the performance boost is because `bispev` exploits the regular grid, while `bispeu` may simply loop through all the index pairs... though I'm not sure).

In any event, I want to call an `.ev` like function in such a way that I can interpolate a grid that may not be completely regular (but is close) and that will be faster than the current call to `bispeu`. "Regularizing" the grid and going with `bispev` IS an option, and the end results are PRETTY close, and the routine is MUCH faster that way (by a factor of 20!)... however, Matlab `interp2` allows the slightly irregular grid and computes with the same speed.  I have considered trying to write my own C function, but I'm highly doubtful that such a lowly one as I can do any better than what's already in Scipy and written by geniuses. :)

So.. is there a way I can have my cake and eat it too?  Is there some awesome little tricky way I can call the spline evaluator?  I have thought about making my own bespoke wrapper for the fitpack calls... but the documentation for fitpack is not readily available (certainly not in the Scipy release I have), and I'd like to avoid that extra work if possible.  Also note that this problem is especially irksome because I'm having to call it twice, once for the real and imaginary components of my original field (Matlab takes complex meshes). At the end of the day, I want to give Matlab the BOOT... but this speed issue could be a killer.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have a look at `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` or `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator` (or the new `interpn` interface to it). Both should be considerably faster than your current approach. I'm a bit short on time, at the moment, so I'll have to skip a full answer.  Hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction, though.

Comment: @Joe Kington Thank you for your response!  Looking at the (sparse) documentation of map_coordinates, it appears that the "grid" is baked in... that is to say that I will need to transform my values at which to interpolate to index space, i.e. [0, 1, ..., n-1]. Did I suss that out correctly? Also, in your opinion, will map_coordinates do the same thing as RBS, as I described in the question? Thanks again for your response... it's very hard to find info on this particular topic.